# Obtener indice de un array dentro de otro array por dos valores buscados en PHP

Tags: php, php7

Tengo un array multidimensional

```
array
{
   [0] => array
   {
      [fecha] => 2024-01-05
      [pago] => 1
      [total] => 125
   }
   [1] => array
   {
      [fecha] => 2024-01-05
      [pago] => 2
      [total] => 12
   }
   [2] => array
   {
      [fecha] => 2024-01-06
      [pago] => 1
      [total] => 250
   }
   [3] => array
   {
      [fecha] => 2024-01-06
      [pago] => 2
      [total] => 180
   }
   [4] => array
   {
      [fecha] => 2024-01-07
      [pago] => 1
      [total] => 100
   }
   [5] => array
   {
      [fecha] => 2024-01-07
      [pago] => 2
      [total] => 75
   }
}
```

Lo que necesito es obtener el indice en el que se encuentra el array que contiene los valores dados.

```
Ejemplo:

fecha = 2024-01-06
pago = 1

indice -> 2
```

Se que con la siguiente función que he creado resuelvo este problema

```
function getIndice($array, $valor1, $valor2)
{
      $pos = 0; 

       foreach($array as $arr)
       {
            if($arr["fecha"] == $valor1 && $arr["pago"] == $valor2)
             {
                    return $pos;
             }
  
             $pos++;
        }

        return false;  
}

$indice = getIndice($ventas, "2019-01-05", 1);
```

Pero habrá alguna otra forma de solucionar esto usando las funciones que ya están definidas en **PHP** como por ejemplo la función `array_search`

Comment: Con `array_search` es posible, pero indícanos primero tus intentos por resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguramente haya mas formas de hacerlo, pero podrias usar `array_filter()` para filtrar el array por los valores que se pasan en los parametros.
Algo asi:

```
$ventas = [
  ["fecha" => "2024-01-05", "pago" => 1, "total" => 125],
  ["fecha" => "2024-03-15", "pago" => 2, "total" => 100],
  ["fecha" => "2024-05-25", "pago" => 3, "total" => 300],
  ["fecha" => "2024-05-25", "pago" => 3, "total" => 305]
];

function buscarIndiceEnArray($ventas, $fecha, $pago)
{
  $ventasFiltradas = array_filter($ventas, function ($venta) use ($fecha, $pago) {
    return $venta["fecha"] === $fecha && $venta["pago"] === $pago;
  });

  return $ventasFiltradas;
}

buscarIndiceEnArray($ventas, "2024-05-25", 3);
```

Eso te va a devolver un array filtrado con los parametros que se pasan a la funcion `buscarIndiceEnArray()`.

```
array:2▼
  2 => array:3 [
    "fecha" => "2024-05-25"
    "pago" => 3
    "total" => 300
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    "fecha" => "2024-05-25"
    "pago" => 3
    "total" => 305
  ]
]
```

`array_filter()` [conserva los indices originales del array filtrado](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php#:%7E:text=Las%20claves%20del%20array%20se%20conservan.). Si solo queres los indices podrias usar:

```
return array_keys($ventasFiltradas);
```

Y eso te va a devolver un array con todos los indices que pasaron las condiciones del filtro.

Comment: Una duda que me surgió en tu propuesta, veo que junto con la función anónima que defines como segundo argumento de array_filter usas la palabra "use" esa palabra es para indicar que los valores de los parámetros $fecha y $pago los use en la comparación que realizas dentro de la función anónima??

Comment: Exacto! Con `use($fecha, $pago)` haces disponibles los valores de esas variables dentro del closure/entorno de la funcion anonima.